# How to move a variable in a c++ function

Tags: c++, function, variables

I am an taking a community college class I need help transferring this variable double sum=mW/hW to equal int femur length. I need it to print out this when the code is done compiling. mW and hW are in mm but need to be converted to cm when it's in the second function. Could someone please help me

> Welcome inspector,
>
> Hair Analysis:
> Please enter the medulla width in mm: 3
> Please enter the entire hair width in mm: 10
>
> Height Analysis:
> Please enter the gender (0 for male 1 for female: 0
> Please enter the femur length in cm: 10
> The height is estimated to be 84.582

This is my code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void getHairtype()
{
    double mW = 0;
    double hW = 0;
    double sum = mW / hW;
    
    // Start of Get hair type fuction
    cout << "Hair Analysis:" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the medulla with in mm" << endl;
    
    //medulla Diameter
    cin >> mW;
    cout << mW << "mm" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the entire hair width in mm." << endl;
    //entire hair
    cin >> hW;
    cout << hW << "mm" << endl;
    // Ratio porptions
    if (sum < .5)
    {
        cout << "1 : This is human hair" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "0: This is animal hair" << endl;
    }
    return;
}

void getHumanHeiegth()
{
    ///Gender
    int gender;
    //femur length
    int femurLength = 0;
    
    double height = 69.089 + (2.238 * femurLength);
    double heightI = 61.412 + (2.317 * femurLength);
    cout << "Height Analysis:" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter a gender (0 for male and 1 for female " << endl;
    cin >> gender;
    cout << " Please enter the femur length" << endl;
    cin >> femurLength;
    if (gender == 0)
    {
        cout << "The estimated hieght is " << height << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The estimated hieght is " << heightI << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout << "Welcome inspector, " << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to accomplish by dividing 0 by 0 in your first function? You declare mW and set it to 0. Ok. You declare HW, also 0. Great. But then you divide one by the other. Why?

Comment: well it gave me an error so I set it equal to zero then I asked the user to input their number so I thought it would change

Comment: you need to move `cin>>femurLength;` to before `double height= 69.089 + (2.238*femurLength);`. C++ is a procedural language. Statements are applied in the written order.

Comment: If you don't understand an error or the real reason for it, making random code changes is unlikely to fix the problem, but only create more problems.

Comment: it would say  mW and hW are uninitialized so I just set it equal to zero

Comment: i wanted sum to equal femur length but they are located in two different functions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your sum variable down, after you've received the input, and also you probably don't need to initialise mW and hW, really is stylistic and code practice.  As for your question on units, I couldn't quite understand it.

If you want to pass variables around you need to either pass them via value, pointer or reference, or the dreaded *global variable*. Please don't do the last one! Passing a variable via value is often the easiest approach, where you essentially just copy the value! This is actually really simple, you just add a parameter to the function definition/declaration and then pass the variable into the function call!

Comment: i wanted sum to equal femur length but they are located in two different functions.

Comment: Ok so you can modify your function to instead of returning void, to return this value or you can pass the value in by reference or by pointer in your main function. Also I'm still unsure by what you mean in this comment, in your second function you never refer to sum?

Comment: yes, I want to pass the value of sum in the first function to femurLength. I don't know how to do that could you show me? I just started i don't understand how to pass variables in functions.

Comment: Since you're only concerned about the one variable you can modify the return type of the first function: `void getHairtype()` to `double getHairType()` and change your `return` to return `sum`, then you can simply add the parameter to the other function `void getHumanHeiegth()` to `void getHumanHeiegth(double foo)`, and access the value inside that function as `foo`, then all you have to do is change how you call the functions in main, either by nesting them `getHumanHeieght(getHairtype())` or with an interim variable!

Comment: so make femurLength equal foo correct and double foo shouldn't look like this correct:(double&foo)

Comment: What you posted second is passing by reference, which is the most common method for passing variables around, however, since you're just passing a double, the performance difference is negligible. As for the first part, you just have to assign femurLength to foo inside the function, you can essentially use foo as you would any other variable. I would recommend looking into C++ scoping and functions for more knowledge around this area.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask again but how would I structure passing by reference I'm really sorry.

Comment: It’s practically the same, but you just stick an ampersand on the function definition’s parameter. The call is the exact same.